# Mesh approximation with fixed-size irregular shapes

Tags: computational-geometry

Suppose I have a mesh that I'd like to approximate the surface of by placing a bunch of irregular objects. Each irregular shape is of fixed-size, but can be rotated in increments of 15 degrees (around the "up" axis in 3D). Their positions are integer co-ordinates. The interior of the mesh does not need to be covered.

See my (poor) attempt to approximate a 2D example in the diagram below.

I've looked into shape approximation, voxelization with geometric set cover, and surface similarity metrics, but find it quite overwhelming and I haven't found quite what I'm looking for. It doesn't need to be a fast algorithm. The criteria are some mix of minimizing object (or polygon) count and "looking good from a distance".

What algorithms do you think would be most fruitful here? What are your go-to tools for tackling and visualizing this kind of problem? e.g. PyMesh, etc.

[image: Shape Approximation]

Comment: I don't see a mesh, just an outline.

Comment: IMO, the problem gets simpler if you expand your base objects in 24 rotated versions (less in case of symmetry). Then you only have to consider translations.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can get closer to a solution by considering the Minkowski difference of the shape to be covered and the individual objects. But I can't tell you more.

Comment: Next hint: consider every object separately and translate it "near" points of the outline. Possibly check if the object does not exceed the outline too much. Then estimate the section of the outline that is covered to a suitable approximation. Finally, find a minimal cover among those sections.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I drew a 2D outline because I didn’t want to attempt to diagram a 3D mesh. Thanks for your advice — I will look into it. Thanks!